# How do I echo a variable then delete everything on the page and repeat

Tags: php, xampp, flush

I've been trying to echo variables while the script is running. I've got that part to work. However, I want to delete everything on the page then echo and repeat. I've searched on stackoverflow, and tried their solutions, but it still doesn't work for me. Example:

1. Delete everything on the page (so its blank).
2. echo `$i`
3. `$i += 1`
4. Repeat

PHP Version: 7.2.10
Running on: XAMPP

**script.php:**

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while ($i < 999999999) {
    echo $i;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
    $i += 1;
}
```

---

What is happening is that the page is not deleting everything on the page so it ends up looking like:

09:00:00

```
0
```

09:00:01

```
01
```

09:00:02

```
012
```

---

I want it to be like this:

09:00:00

```
0
```

09:00:01

```
1
```

09:00:02

```
2
```

Comment: Ross - flushing data does exactly that - nothing in the script would clear the display. For that, you might want to look into something like Javascript with ajax so you can communicate with your PHP backend

Comment: @DerekPollard Is there any function in php that would do it?

Comment: No, that would be something for javascript to handle. Unless you had PHP just simply refreshing the paging every X seconds, which I don't recommend

Comment: @DerekPollard sorry, this question is a little off topic but you just made me very concerned. Javascript is executed client side. That means using Javascript I can call PHP functions. Does this means people can edit the source code (using Google Chrome by pressing `F12`, then editing code in the elements section) and execute any of my php functions, if they figure out my php function's name?

Comment: php runs on the server side. That means the client gets only what you send to them. plain text, html files, json, or what ever you want. That means,when the content gets once send to the client there is no way for the server to clear the display/page on the client side. If you want to change the content of the page, use ajax calls from js to your webserver for receiving the content you want.

Comment: Any client can execute any server side function _that you published_ , so explicitly made available as an endpoint. It can _not_ somehow execute arbitrary functions. How should it do that? It can only send http requests, there is no other magic connection between the client and the server.

Comment: @Marc say I have a function called `secret` and it returns `apples`. If the client figures out my function is called `secret` can they make an ajex request to call the `secret` function and see that the answer is `apples`?

Comment: @arkascha If I tell the user my function is called `secret` they can make a post request to the secret function and know my `secret` returns `apples`?

Comment: @ross that depends on how you create your api structure! just because you have php function dosnt mean the user can call it via ajax.

Comment: No, tell me: how should you request a _function_ by making a http request? You can only request a URL from the client side. If the server responds to that URL and how is up to the server. So _you_ decide what your server does, how it reacts. If you map a URL to a function, then sure, that function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, using JS to clear the page during the while loop

```
$i = 0;
        while ($i < 10) {
            echo $i;
            flush();
            ob_flush();
            sleep(1);
            $i += 1;
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "document.body.innerHTML = ''";
            echo "</script>";
        }
```

Comment: isn't this going to print the js part a lot and the html code will be filled with this code? Hence, taking up a lot of ram?

Comment: @Ross A lot of RAM? Not on the server side, not at all and on the client side, well, today's computers have many gigabytes of RAM. Above code would sum up to roughly 1 kilobyte...

Comment: @Ross I don't know about that ngl but I don't think it'll take up too much as it's very simple code. What you're asking for is weird and I don't see many other ways to do it tbh.

Comment: I think you're worried about the wrong things @Ross - websites ship down more javascript than ever before these days.

Comment: This code will show you a white screen - php is a server side languge and show only the result.

Comment: @Maksim have you tested the code? Works beautifully on my end.

Comment: Yes, tesdted - and seen white screen :)

Answer (score 0):

if I not wrong, only way to achive this is javascript or CSS because "output" in PHP is always show in client side, and as you know well, PHP doesn't change anything in client side.

```
<?php                                      
$i = 0;
   while ($i < 999999999) {
 echo '<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;background:white;width:15px;">&nbsp;</div>'; // to clean
 echo '<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0">'.$i.'</div>'; // to show in same place.
flush(); 
ob_flush(); 
sleep(1);
$i += 1;
}
?>
```

In any case, hope this help for you.

Comment: If I do this, this will chew up the client's ram up pretty fast

Comment: this cuestion is look like a "homework" but this is not my concern. Wherever.. I think this is not achive with only PHP, because you know, only control server side, not output place (client side).